# loading multiple line query in one row

Tags: mysql

How to load a multiple line query in one row using mysql.The data is stored in a text file.
For example:
 "GGAGTTGTGGGAGTGGAGGAGGAAGAGGCGGTGGGGAGTACGGGGGCTGGTCCCAGAAGATGGCGGAGGC
GGGGGATTTCTGGTAGGTCCTACTTTAGGACAAGATGTGGTGGTACTGTTGAAGCGTCAGTCTTTGATTC"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dna_strands SET base_sequence = "GGAGTTG
TGGGAGTGGAGGAGGAAGAGGCGGTGGGG
AGTACGGGGGCTGGTCCCAGAAGATGGCGGAGGC
GGGGGATTTCTGGTAGGTCCTACTTTAGGACAAGATGTGG
TGGTACTGTTGAAGCGTCAGTCTTTGATTC";
```

As long as you're escaping the input correctly, MySQL doesn't care that the sequence of characters contains linebreaks.

Comment: But surely the linebreaks are stored as part of the data - and DNA doesn't have a line breaks! So presumably bharath should be removing the linebreaks before constructing the insert?

Comment: Maybe; but in the absence of further information, we could speculate about the data and about bharath's business logic till we're blue in the face ;)